# Stop Uploading blank app to store, full app to testflight?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have written an AR app in xCode (coding newbie), but when I send it off to apple all they receive is a blank/unpopulated AR kit app (ie straight to camera mode).

They have suggested that I am sending a test flight version, and not a full version, and so every time I upload what I believe to be a fully working app taking onboard their comments, they still only see the camera.

This has been going on for months now and both I and they are loosing the will.

Does anybody have any idea how to stop it sending a blank app, and to get it to send what I can see when I test it at my end?

I have tried changing the build number and version number but still no change.

I just do not understand why they are not receiving what I can see.
All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing from TestFlight yourself? this is the same binary that you submit to Apple. What steps are you using to upload your binary? Archive->Distribute to AppStore?

Comment: I am awaiting authorisation for the uploaded version to be accepted in testflight.
I have just exported from organiser an ad hoc version to my desktop, and using 'Devices and Simulators' have removed the version that was on the device and loaded this new version (the same as sent to apple) and everything is as I would expect to see.... so not sure why apple are not seeing this.

Yes, Archive->Distribute to app store etc etc... It seems to work alright my end and the file gets bigger as I add more stuff to it, but they do not seem able to see it.

Comment: You don't need authorisation for TestFlight - It takes a few minutes for the binary upload to be processed, but once it is you can add yourself as a TestFlight user and install it.  You only need approval to make it available to external testers.

Comment: Ok, I have now also tested in testflight and can see as I would expect, so how do I turn this version (that seems to work for me both pre-upload and post-upload) into a version that can be viewed by apple. I have been working on this since June, and it has taken this much time for apple to say they cannot see anything other than the basic ARkit experience.

Comment: Sorry me again.... So, if it works locally and in testflight, is there anything else I need to change to enable the testflight version be seen by apple? and for it to be published onto the app store?

Comment: No, simply select that build and submit for review

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I have been trying to get sense out of Apple.

They say "While your testflight build might reflect the changes you have made, it does not reflect this current build for production. 
It would be appropriate to submit the ready for production for review."

It seems every update I have done has been going to testflight and not to the app store for review.

The question is what am I failing to do to get the app to not go to testflight?
I believe I have followed their instructions to a t, and for the life of me where I am going wrong.

HELP! :) 
Thank you

Comment: When you upload a build it is available for TestFlight and for review. To actually submit it for review, you need to go to your app in AppStore Connect, go to the version you are submitting for review, and select the build that you want to submit. Then save and submit for review.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but I am so close and yet so far.
I select the build in testflight?
In testflight when I select the build but see no save and submit for review button.
I do not know where else to see the build. (I really feel stupid sorry, but help is hugely appreciated)

Comment: Sorry I now see the version that is sent for review, but the latest version is not listed, it still shows the first version.
How do I navigate this to the latest version?

Comment: You need to remove the build first, if you haven't already done so, and hen select the new build. The version number in the build that you archived and uploaded must match the version number of the app in AppStore Connect or the build won't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has resolved my problem - THANK YOU SO SO MUCH!!!! This has been driving me MAD! **The hidden delete button next to the build did not help!!!!!** THANK YOU Paulw11 !
Once you delete the version you can select the new version..... (it should not be this hard)